# how to create dataframe like this (provide daily first trip record) by using R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I want to change my dataframe like this. How can I do it in R? Do I need double For loops to achieve this ?

```
ID  DATE        Origin 
1   01/01/2012  A
1   01/01/2012  B
1   01/01/2012  C
1   01/02/2012  A
1   01/02/2012  B
1   01/02/2012  C
1   01/03/2012  A
1   01/03/2012  B
1   01/08/2012  A
2   01/01/2012  D
2   01/01/2012  C
2   01/01/2012  B
2   01/04/2012  D
2   01/04/2012  C
2   01/06/2012  D
3   01/03/2012  F
3   01/03/2012  G
3   01/09/2012  F
3   01/09/2012  G


 ID DATE        Origin
    1   01/01/2012  A
    1   01/02/2012  A
    1   01/03/2012  A
    1   01/08/2012  A
    2   01/01/2012  D
    2   01/04/2012  D
    2   01/06/2012  D
    3   01/03/2012  F
    3   01/09/2012  F
```

(I only want to remain the record like this one ↑) 
(**daily first trip** record for each passenger)
no matter how many travels he did in one day just remain the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(Origin ~ ID + DATE, data=x, FUN='[', i=1)
##   ID       DATE Origin
## 1  1 01/01/2012      A
## 2  2 01/01/2012      D
## 3  1 01/02/2012      A
## 4  1 01/03/2012      A
## 5  3 01/03/2012      F
## 6  2 01/04/2012      D
## 7  2 01/06/2012      D
## 8  1 01/08/2012      A
## 9  3 01/09/2012      F
```

Group by `ID` and `DATE`, taking the first value for `Origin` in each group.

Comment: As an aside, I thought named arguments to `[` were explicitly discouraged, as `(1:3)[u=1]`  and `(1:3)[fdsa=1]` and `(1:3)[i=1]` all give the same result.

Comment: @thelatemail Perhaps it is just me, but to me it is more readable to name the (single) argument to `[` when it is called by `aggregate` or `*apply` or such.  It makes it clear that the `1` is not an argument for `aggregate` itself.

Comment: Fair enough, I remembered where I saw the official discouragement - `data.frame(a=1:3)[i=3]` for instance.